# Zig - Initializing a slice literal of union enum

Tags: initialization, slice, unions, literals, zig

I have the following types:

```
    const ParsedValType = enum { String, Integer, List, Dict };
    const ParsedVal = union(enum) {
        String: []const u8,
        Integer: i64,
        List: []const ParsedVal,
        Dict: []DictEntry,
    };
    const DictEntry = struct { k: []const u8, v: ParsedVal };
```

I am having big trouble prototyping in Zig and I am wasting a reasonable amount of time on something which should be relatively easy to do. I would like to somehow initialize a literal slice, so I can play around with it by doing the following:

```
var x = &[_]ParsedVal{
        .{ .String = "string here" },
        .{ .Integer = 55 },
        .{ .List = []const ParsedVal{ .String = "asdfsdf" } },
    };
```

That code works fine for the `.String` and `.Integer`, however when I try to run the program with `.List` I get the following error:

```
error: type '[]const main.ParsedVal' does not support struct initialization syntax
        .{ .List = []const ParsedVal{ .String = "asdfsdf" } },
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I have tried many different variations to initialize the `.List` field, but without success.
How can I just initalize a literal slice and then loop on it like that:

```
for (x) |val| {
        switch (val) {
            .String => |s| std.debug.print("string: {s}\n", .{s}),
            .Integer => |d| std.debug.print("integer: {d}\n", .{d}),
            .List => |l| std.debug.print("list {any}\n", .{l}),
            .Dict => |d| std.debug.print("dictionary {any}\n", .{d}),
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for [an array literal coerced to slice](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#Type-Coercion-Slices-Arrays-and-Pointers) is:

```
&[_]TheType{ value1, value2, ... }
```

And each value needs its own initialization syntax. E.g. `ParsedVal{ .String = "..." }` or, using [anonymous union literals](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#Anonymous-Union-Literals) syntax, `.{ .String = "..." }`.

The corrected syntax for initializing the `.List` field looks like this:

```
.{ .List = &[_]ParsedVal{ .{ .String = "asdfsdf" } } }
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how I can remove the following cast, when trying to initialize a list of dict structs: .{
            .Dict = @constCast(&[_]DictEntry{
                .{
                    .k = "key",
                    .v = .{ .String = "value" },
                },
            }),
        }, . The syntax to me is super non-intuitive and without casting I am clueless how to initialize the dict field.

Comment: @unknownerror Make elements of the `.Dict` constant in the `ParsedVal` union. The same as you did with the other slices: `Dict: []const DictEntry`

Comment: That's what I was thinking as well. I was just wondering if I can achieve that without changing the type nor using a cast.

Comment: @unknownerror There is no good way to solve it. Because what's happening here is that you're making an array literal in [the global constant data section, by the looks of it](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#Memory), and casting it to a slice. Allowing implicit const to non-const [cast](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#Casting) would make it seem like you can do whatever you want with that memory, which isn't true.